# Replacement for DispatchQueue.main.after in Swift 3 beta 4

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, swift3

The compiler does not accept this construct any longer and the replacement may be:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadLine: delayTime, execute:)
```

But even that produces an error hinting to no available overload.
What is the right construct to perform this function?

Comment: Works for me. Just add a dispatch time and a closure. `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now(), execute: { print("Hello") })`

Comment: Right. Th error was in the capital L. Surely Xcode errors are not that helpful.

Comment: Yeah sometimes error messages are not helpful. They keep improving, though. :) Let's close this question as "simple typo" if you're ok with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right spelling, as suggested by Eric, is:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime, execute:)
```

With a non capital l. Of course Xcode takes you astray if you commit this sort of errors.